# Use of undefined constant jquery - assumed 'jquery' - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I couldn't find out this issues. Please help me

[image]

> Warning: Use of undefined constant jquery - assumed 'jquery' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\shihabseo\wp-content\themes\consult\inc\enqueue.php on
>   line 36

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPIA.png)

Comment: please share relevant code like line 36 on enqueue.php

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('jquery-magnific', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array(jquery), '1.0.0', 'true');

Answer (score 4):

In array, you don't need to me

**Change this:** `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-magnific', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array(jquery), '1.0.0', 'true');`

**TO this:** `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-magnific', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', 'true');`

Answer (score 1):

You quoted the following code:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery-magnific', 
    get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',                 
    array(jquery), 
    '1.0.0', 
    'true');
```

(I've exploded it across several lines to make it easier to read/reference.)
The parameters for `wp_enqueue_script()` are:

1. handle (string)
2. src/url (string)
3. dependencies (array of strings)
4. version (string|bool|null)
5. in_footer (bool)

Your issues is in parameter #3. Presumably this 'jquery-magnific' library is dependent on jQuery. Specifying it in #3 instructs WP to load that library first (if possible).

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery-magnific', 
    get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', 
    array('jquery'), 
    '1.0.0', 
    'true');
```

More Improvements:

- Consider using the short array syntax, now that we're in the PHP7 era: `['jquery']`.
- As someone suggested above, you should consider using a CDN for your `magnific-popup.min.js` script, rather than hosting it and loading it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance forget to use the $ for variable or forget to put parenthesis on a function name?
It'd be much better if you can share the code snippet.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/modernizr.js', array(jquery), '1.0.0', 'true');

Comment: Please check the response from madalinivascu.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the word in quotes 'jquery' to make it a string, right now you are using it as a [php constant](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.constants.php)

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
```